# Which keyserver to use for Verifying signatures with GnuPG for YubiHSM SDK signature verification

Tags: keyserver, yubihsm

From the following URL I have downloaded the YubiHSM SDK https://developers.yubico.com/YubiHSM2/Releases/.

However the other URL says we need to validate the package by downloading the keys which is specified from the following URL: https://developers.yubico.com/Software_Projects/Software_Signing.html

However what is the keyserver do we need to use to download a key?

I will be using the following command to receive a key:

```
gpg --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys 70D7145F2F35C4745501829A1B21578FC4686BFE
```

And the command output is as following:

> *gpg: keyserver receive failed: Server indicated a failure*

Answer (score 1):

PGP key servers synchronise their keys so it shouldn't matter which one you use. Also, your system should be configured already to use a pool of key servers, so the `--keyserver` option is not required.

Try without the `--keyserver` option.

If that doesn't work, try with an alternative key server. For instance keyserver.ubuntu.com, sks.pgpkeys.eu, or keys.openpgp.org.